# Comparing two JavaScript statements - are they equivalent?

Tags: javascript

Are these two statements equivalent?

```
var var1 = var2 ? var2 : 0;

var var1 = var2 || 0;
```

Seems like yes, however I'm not sure.

var2 is (probably) defined above.

Comment: Yes both means the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they're not:

```
> var i=0;
> with({ get var2() { return ++i; } }) {
>    var var1 = var2 || 0;
> }
> var1
1
> var i=0;
> with({ get var2() { return ++i; } }) {
>     var var1 = var2 ? var2 : 0;
> }
> var1
2
```

As you can see, the second one evaluates `var2` twice. However, this is the only difference, and one that hardly matters for "normal" variables.

Comment: It's a very contrived example, though :-)

Comment: Aye, though it's always interesting to learn more about the 'guts' of Javascript regardless if you'd ever apply them to your code!

Comment: To be pedantic: the equivalence of the operations depends on the value of `var2`. If it's falsey it's not evaluated twice. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are equivalent. Both statements evaluate to `var2` if and only if `var2` is a truthy value (i.e. not zero, NaN, false, null, or the empty string).

Note that this assumes evaluating `var2` has no side-effects, which applies in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: You forgot `undefined` ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling: I did consider `undefined`, but I had heard stuff about reassigning `undefined` and I'm just about all of confused so I wasn't sure if I should include it :P

Comment: Yeah, `undefined` can be confusing: The problem with the token `undefined` in *source code* is that it's not a literal, like `null`, but actually a global variable. And hence it was possible to assign a new value to it. However, that's not possible anymore in modern browsers and the *value* `undefined` is falsey, regardless of the value of the *variable* `undefined`.

Comment: @Felix Kling: That makes sense - I was just trying to reassign it using the console but to no avail. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2):

In this context they are identical in the sense that they both test the *truthiness* of `var2`.

Obviously though the ternary variant has more flavor to it should you want to test the variable for something other than whether or not the value is true.